# PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT recreates Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have a notification and when I tap it I want to launch application if it is still not running, but if application already running, I do not want to relaunch it.
So, I am using `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` flag when creating `PendingIntent`.

My code:

```
private val notificationManager by lazy { NotificationManagerCompat.from(this) }

fun testPush() {
        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ill_launcher)

        notificationBuilder
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setContentText("Test text")
                .setContentIntent(buildPendingIntent())

        notificationBuilder
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .priority = NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT

        notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build())
}

 private fun buildPendingIntent(): PendingIntent {

        val intent = Intent(this, RootActivity::class.java)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
        intent.putExtra("action", RootActivity.DEFAULT_INTENT)

        return PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
}
```

But when I launch the application and click on the notification, the activity is recreates.

Comment: `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` does not have that effect. That says that you want to update the extras of the `Intent`, if there is already a `PendingIntent` for an equivalent `Intent`. It says nothing about whether you want to reuse an existing activity instance.

Comment: @CommonsWare so, I need to set some flags to the `Intent` to get described effect, right? Here: `intent.flags = Intent.<SOME_FLAG>`. Documentation says, that `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` will work in described way: "the activity will not be launched if it is already running at the top of the history stack". But my application doesn't work that way.

Comment: By default, you will wind up with a new task, since the `PendingIntent` is being invoked from something than one of your task's existing activities. IIRC, you need to adjust some task-related attributes in your `<activity>` element in the manifest.

Comment: @CommonsWare can you provide example, please? Do you mean smth like `android:launchMode` attribute?

Comment: I don't have a sample for this handy, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of building the `Intent` for `RootActivity` like you are doing, you need to create a "launch `Intent`" for your application. The easiest way to do this is to call `PackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage()` and pass your own package name. Use the returned `Intent` in the call to `PendingIntent.getActivity()`.

This will launch your app if it isn't running, otherwise, if it is already running, it will just bring the existing task containing your app to the foreground.

Comment: it still recreates the activity

Comment: hard to believe. Please edit your question and post your manifest and also the code you use to create the `PendingIntent`. Also how do you know that the `Activity` is recreated?

Comment: Try Android 6, 7